# Missing image when shared using UIActivityViewController

Tags: facebook, uiactivityviewcontroller

We've the following method to share content in the application. For each content we share:

- Text
- Image
- URL

```html
+ (void) generalShare:(NSString *) text withEntity:(SMEntity *) theEntity onView:(UIViewController*) theViewController withImage:(UIImage *) image completion:(void (^)(void))completion
    {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:templateURL
                                           , [SMSocialManager getAction:theEntity]
                                           , [theEntity getId]]];
        NSArray *sharingItems = @[text, url, image];
        
        UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:sharingItems applicationActivities:nil];
        [activityController setValue:text forKey:@"subject"];
        
        [UINavigationBar appearance].barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
        [UINavigationBar appearance].translucent = NO;
        [UINavigationBar appearance].barTintColor = UIColorFromRGB(SMPrimaryColor);
    
        [theViewController presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:^{
            return completion();
        }];
    }
```

Until a few time it works perfectly, a few time ago the text was missing when you try to share in facebook (based on the new policy) but just a days ago the image, is also missing, and just the URL is included.

Any suggestions?

I could figure out generating an ad-hoc solution for each destination social network, but find a way to solve with an standard solution could be better approach.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It seams facebook and instagram removed the caption from the integration, and I don't know why but with facebook also the image is not working anymore.